# Getting "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Microsoft.'

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I'm getting an error, "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'Microsoft.'

Here is the code:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim stSQL As String




Public Sub loadData()
 'This was set up using Microsoft  ActiveX Data Components version 6.0.



 'Create ADODB connection object, open connection and 
 '       construct the connection string object which is the DSN name.
 Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
 conn.ConnectionString = "sql_server"

conn.Open
'conn.Execute (strSQL)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'Open Excel and run query to export data to SQL Server.
strSQL = "SELECT * INTO SalesOrders " & _
         "FROM OPENDATASOURCE(Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
         "Data Source=C:\Workbook.xlsx;" & _
         "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0; [Sales Orders])"

conn.Execute (strSQL)

'Error handling.
ErrorExit:
 'Reclaim memory from the cntection objects
 Set rst = Nothing
 Set conn = Nothing

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
   MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
   Resume ErrorExit


'clean up and reclaim memory resources.
conn.Close
If CBool(cnt.State And adStateOpen) Then
Set rst = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing

End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provider argument passed to OPENDATASOURCE is a string so must be quoted.
Your also addressing the sheet within the OPENDATASOURCE call, which is incorrect;

```
     strSQL = "SELECT * INTO SalesOrders " & _
       "FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0'," & _
       "'Data Source=C:\Workbook.xlsx;" & _
       "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0')...[Sales Orders]"
```

Comment: Ok. I see what you mean.  I've made the changes, but now I get [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Unspecified error".

Comment: Make sure the account under which your running that query has permissions to access the file (probably needs read & write) & make sure the file isn't open anywhere else.
(Also remember the C:\ in that path is the C drive on the server!)

Comment: Thanks for your help Alex.  You too Raj!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following syntax

xls

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=[FilePath];Extended Properties=”Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1”
```

xlsx

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=[FilePath];Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1
```

HDR=Yes specifies that the first row of the data contains column names and not data so set it accordingly (Yes, No)

IMEX=1  specifies that the driver should always read the “intermixed” data columns as text

ref: http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2009/05/02/uploading-an-excel-file-to-sql-through-an-asp-net-webform.aspx

Comment: I put in the 'Provider=Microsoft...' but now instead of "Incorrect Syntax Near Microsoft," I get "Incorrect syntax near Provider."